Open with code in context menu when clicked shows application error
I installed VS code on my laptop and then i uninstalled it.. but "open with code" in the context menu is still there... Now I have installed the vs code again and when I click on that option in Contact menu it shows application not found.
I need the correct solution
I tried to uninstall and install it again but have the same result
